# Redirecionamento diferentes por dia da semana

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

 $site[] = 'youtube.com';
 $site[] = 'facebook.com';

$destino = rand(0, (count($site) - 1));

header("Location: " . $site[$destino]);
?>
```

Galera, uso este script para fazer um redirecionamento aleatorio. O script vai escolher entre as duas variaveis e vai redirecionar, simples. Mas eu queria ajuda para alterar isso por dia. Exemplo, na segunda as variaveis seriam

```
$site[] = 'youtube.com';
$site[] = 'facebook.com';
```

Na terça seria

```
$site[] = 'exemplo.com';
$site[] = 'mangaonli.com';
```

E assim por diante. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro você vai fazer um array, com os dias da semana em ingles contendo um array de links para cada dia da semana, aqui no exemplo estou usando as 3 primeiras letras pois vou usar `date("D")`, mas poderia ser o nome completo para usar `date("l")` ou até mesmo númericos de `0-6` para usar `date("w")`:

```
$dias_e_links=array(
    "Mon"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
    "Tue"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
    "Wed"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
    "Thu"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
    "Fri"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
    "Sat"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
    "Sun"=>array(
        "link1.com",
        "link2.com",
        "link3.com"
    ),
);
```

Agora é só pegar o dia de hoje e dar o `rand()` nos links:

```
$hoje = date("D");
$destino = rand(0, (count($dias_e_links[$hoje]) - 1));
header("Location: " . $dias_e_links[$hoje][$destino]);
```

**Lembrando que é apenas uma das maneiras possíveis, porém achei a mais simples**

> [Documentação da função date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Valeu, cara. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: Se puder me dar uma ajuda nessa eu agradeço, cara:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380999/aleat%C3%B3rio-entre-hor%C3%A1rio